# Edit css of "item" when clicking on corresponding "btn"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this

```
<div class="btns">
    <div class="btn1"></div>
    <div class="btn2"></div>
    <div class="btn3"></div>
    <div class="btn4"></div>
</div>

<div class="prevs">
    <div class="pre1"></div>
    <div class="pre2"></div>
    <div class="pre3"></div>
    <div class="pre4"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uzpxjukv/

You have btn1, btn2, btn3 and btn4. I'm trying to make it so that when you press btn1, the div with the class pre1 should then get "display: block;" or something to make it visible. Then when btn2 is clicked, pre1 turns invisible again and pre2 turns visible.

Comment: Smells like homework... - What have you tried so far? Anything more than the "empty" fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFIDDLE DEMO -> http://jsfiddle.net/uzpxjukv/5/

```
$('.btns div').click(function() {
    var classNumber = this.className.slice(-1);
    $('.prevs div').hide();
    $('.pre' + classNumber).show();
});
```

On click of the button div, first hide all the `pre` divs and then show only the relevant div.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? If there will be more buttons, it should be more optimalized.

```
$('.btns').find('div').click(function(){
    $('.prevs').find('div').eq($(this).index()).toggle();
});
```

```js
$('.btns').find('div').click(function(){
        $('.prevs').find('div').eq($(this).index()).toggle();
    });
```

```css
.prevs div:not(.pre1) {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns">
    <div class="btn1">Button 1</div>
    <div class="btn2">Button 2</div>
    <div class="btn3">Button 3</div>
    <div class="btn4">Button 4</div>
</div>

<div class="prevs">
    <div class="pre1">Previews 1</div>
    <div class="pre2">Previews 2</div>
    <div class="pre3">Previews 3</div>
    <div class="pre4">Previews 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$('.btns > div').on('click', function() {
  var numberOfDiv = $(this).attr('class').slice('-1'),
      prevs = $('.prevs');

      prevs.find('> div').hide();
      prevs.find('.pre' + numberOfDiv).show();
});
```

This example is with your html code, if is possible to change it, you can get a better code.

Answer (score 0):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/uzpxjukv/2/)

I have changed your HTML a little bit..Changed the class attribute of the `prevs` divsti ids.

**HTML**

```
<div class="btns">
    <div class="btn1" id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>
    <div class="btn2" id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>
    <div class="btn3" id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>
    <div class="btn4" id="4" onClick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>
</div>
<div class="prevs">
    <div id="pre1"></div>
    <div id="pre2"></div>
    <div id="pre3"></div>
    <div id="pre4"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function reply_click(id) {
    document.getElementById("pre" + id).style.display = "block";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you know what naming system the divs use, you could use something along these lines. (To see properly working, view using developer tool)

```js
$('.btns div').on('click', function() {
  var currClass = $(this).attr('class').slice(-1); //get end of number of div clicked
  $('.prevs div').css('display', 'none'); //reset all divs to being hidden
  $('.pre' + currClass).css('display', 'inline-block'); //show desired div
});
```

```css
.btns div {
  background-color: gray;
}
.btns div, .prevs div {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0.2em;
}

.prevs div {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns">
    <div class="btn1"></div>
    <div class="btn2"></div>
    <div class="btn3"></div>
    <div class="btn4"></div>
</div>

<div class="prevs">
    <div class="pre1"></div>
    <div class="pre2"></div>
    <div class="pre3"></div>
    <div class="pre4"></div>
</div>
```